# Visual Studio App Center: System.NullReferenceException. How can I find the issue?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I don't know what is wrong with my code because everything seems to be correct. Therefore I want to use App Center to find the issue. I have an iOS application and a similar Android application. I uploaded the applications to the Apple App Store and Google Play Store. The applications are in alpha/test mode in both stores. After that, I installed the applications on my iOS and Android device and App Center logged the stack traces after the exception happened but I still cannot find the issue because the stack traces are not detailed enough.

On Android, PlayFab receipt validation always fails and I get this exception

> System.NullReferenceException(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).

On iOS, I think `PlayFab` receipt validation never fails but I sometimes get the same exception

> System.NullReferenceException(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).

The variables `PurchaseditemCurrencyCode`, `PurchaseditemPurchasePrice`, `SignedData` and `Signature` are not null and I think that they have the correct values because I can see in my `Google Play` account that the in-app product purchase is successful, but in the `PlayFab Game Manager` receipt validation fails.

[PlayFab iOS and Android receipt validation](https://blog.playfab.com//blog/show-me-money-receipt-validation-ios-and-android/)

My values on Android:

```
PurchaseditemCurrencyCode = "EUR", 
PurchaseditemPurchasePrice = 229, 
SignedData = "{\"orderId\":..." and Signature = "eMU3xCYDD4L..."
```

My Android stack trace:

```
    {
    "length": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "id": "63783019-f17b-47e1-8865-4e6290f43fbd",
    "exception": {
    "type": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object",
    "stackTrace": "  at ggdgdgd.Android.Game1.ValidateAndroidReceiptAsync (System.String purchaseditemcurrencycode, System.Int32 purchaseditempurchaseprice, System.String signeddata, System.String signature) [0x000c3] in <11446e8c56cb4e78a270889c3b890601>:0 \n  at ggdgdgd.Android.Game1.DoValidateAndroidReceiptAsync (System.String purchaseditemcurrencycode, System.Int32 purchaseditempurchaseprice, System.String signeddata, System.String signature) [0x0007a] in <11446e8c56cb4e78a270889c3b890601>:0 \n  at ggdgdgd.Android.Game1.CheckPurchase (System.String productId) [0x0030a] in <11446e8c56cb4e78a270889c3b890601>:0 ",
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin"
    },
```

My values on iOS:

```
PurchaseditemCurrencyCode = "EUR", 
PurchaseditemPurchasePrice = 229, 
SignedData = "MllVSAYJK..."
```

My iOS stack trace:

```
    {
    "length": 0,
    "offset": 0,
    "id": "71aef385-bb48-44d7-b59d-a53368c72c66",
    "exception": {
    "type": "System.NullReferenceException",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object",
    "stackTrace": "  at InapppurchaseTest.iOS.Game1.ValidateIOSReceiptAsync (System.String purchaseditemcurrencycode, System.Int32 purchaseditempurchaseprice, System.String signeddata, System.String signature) <0x1047fa730 + 0x002dc> in <f7cd0204315c470baa0e7963fe272e8d#b28b8328fb987f6bc8a6ed35dda86f7b>:0 \n  at InapppurchaseTest.iOS.Game1.DoValidateIOSReceiptAsync (System.String purchaseditemcurrencycode, System.Int32 purchaseditempurchaseprice, System.String signeddata, System.String signature) <0x1047fa4e0 + 0x00183> in <f7cd0204315c470baa0e7963fe272e8d#b28b8328fb987f6bc8a6ed35dda86f7b>:0 \n  at InapppurchaseTest.iOS.Game1.CheckPurchase (System.String productId) <0x1047f7a00 + 0x0041f> in <f7cd0204315c470baa0e7963fe272e8d#b28b8328fb987f6bc8a6ed35dda86f7b>:0 ",
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin"
    },
```

It's impossible for me to find the issue with the current stack traces. Is it possible to get a more detailed stack trace in `Visual Studio App Center`?

I think that there is something wrong with **PlayFabClientAPI.ValidateIOSReceiptAsync** and **PlayFabClientAPI.ValidateGooglePlayPurchaseAsync** but I don't know what.

My Android and iOS code:

```
    string SignedData = "", Signature = "", PurchaseditemCurrencyCode = "", PurchaseMessage = "";
    int PurchaseditemPurchasePrice;

    async void CheckPurchase(string productId)
    {
      bool purchaseIsSuccessful = await PurchaseItem(productId, "");

      if (purchaseIsSuccessful == true)
      {
        try
        {
          if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
          {
            if (productId == "Consumable11")
              await DoValidateIOSReceiptAsync(PurchaseditemCurrencyCode, PurchaseditemPurchasePrice, SignedData);
          }
          else
          {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
              if (productId == "Consumable11")
                await DoValidateAndroidReceiptAsync(PurchaseditemCurrencyCode, PurchaseditemPurchasePrice, SignedData, Signature);
            }
          }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
          Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        PurchaseMessage = "Product could not be purchased";
      }
    }

      public async Task DoValidateAndroidReceiptAsync(string purchaseditemcurrencycode, int purchaseditempurchaseprice, string signeddata, string signature)
      {
        await ValidateAndroidReceiptAsync(purchaseditemcurrencycode, purchaseditempurchaseprice, signeddata, signature);
      }

      private async Task ValidateAndroidReceiptAsync(string purchaseditemcurrencycode, int purchaseditempurchaseprice, string signeddata, string signature)
      {
        var result = await PlayFabClientAPI.ValidateGooglePlayPurchaseAsync(new ValidateGooglePlayPurchaseRequest()
        {
        CurrencyCode = purchaseditemcurrencycode,
        PurchasePrice = (uint)purchaseditempurchaseprice,
        ReceiptJson = signeddata,
        Signature = signature
        });

        if (result.Error != null)
          PlayFabMessage = "not successful");
        else
          PlayFabMessage = "successful");
      }


      public async Task DoValidateIOSReceiptAsync(string purchaseditemcurrencycode, int purchaseditempurchaseprice, string signeddata)
      {
        await ValidateIOSReceiptAsync(purchaseditemcurrencycode, purchaseditempurchaseprice, signeddata);
      }

      private async Task ValidateIOSReceiptAsync(string purchaseditemcurrencycode, int purchaseditempurchaseprice, string signeddata)
      {
        var result = await PlayFabClientAPI.ValidateIOSReceiptAsync(new ValidateIOSReceiptRequest()
        {
        CurrencyCode = purchaseditemcurrencycode,
        PurchasePrice = purchaseditempurchaseprice,
        ReceiptData = signeddata
        });

        if (result.Error != null)
          PlayFabMessage = "not successful");
        else
          PlayFabMessage = "successful");
      }
```

Comment: Can you test the code on your local machine and add some breakpoints there to see what is null?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `result` can be `null` and you are not checking that. That's the only point of failure that I can see.

Comment: I want to find out why it is null. On Android, PlayFab receipt validation always fails because there is no receipt validation notification in my PlayFab title account(Game Manager). On iOS, there is a receipt validation notification(validation successful) in my PlayFab title account even if I get the "System.NullReferenceException(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)" exception in App Center.